# 0001. elif skipped[beginner]

Tags: python-3.x, if-statement, flow-control

Please let me know why ***elif*** is being ignored?
I did get several hits on this topic, however those were not much of help.

```
print('Name?')
name=input()
if name=='Alex':
    print('ok')
    print('Age?')
    age=input()
elif age<12:
    print('Nice')

outputs:
Name?
Alex
ok
Age?
11
>>> 
Name?
Joe
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/User/Documents/python/0006.Practice_o2.py", line 7, in <module>
    elif age<12:
NameError: name 'age' is not defined
>>>
```

Comment: i recommend you to start from [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/executionmodel.html)

Answer (score 0):

Try this. You should have *if age<12* inside the parent if

```
print('Name?')
name=input()
if name=='Alex':
    print('ok')
    print('Age?')
    age=input()
    if age<12:
       print('Nice')
```